# Foreign table foriegn key value always showing null ef core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

eWhy is my Icollection foreign key always blank I have a foreign table called photos which I have created using the Icollection. Im using ef core 3.1.7 and asp.net core 3.1 how does one get the file attachments VesselsId not to be null

Basically one vessel can have many photos but their could also be many vessels.

```
 public class Vessels  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(400)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FlagName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FileAttachments> PhotosAttachments { get; set; }

}
```

This is the file attachments

```
public  class FileAttachments {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string File { set; get; }
}
```

In where I Wish to display the photos their blank I use the include statement to try and include them in my query.

```
  var vessels = await _context.Vessels.Where(w=>w.Id==id).Include(c=>c.PhotosAttachments).FirstAsync();
```

But If I look here it will show PhotosAttachments being of null when I look at the field value sure enough its sitting there null.

[image]

I think i need to do something here but im not sure as to what

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**Edit 2**

Basically i have a generic Upload Files method as such which is called via the submit button

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> FormFile, int UploadArea, int PoiId, int VesselId) {     

       FileAttachments attachments = new FileAttachments {
       DocumentPath = filePath,
       UploadAreaId = UploadArea,
       CaseId = resultCaseId,                        
       FullPath = savedFileName,
       FileSize = infoFile.Length,
       OrignalFileName = fileAttachments.FileName,
       FileAttachmentType = fileAttachmentType,
       TennantId = await GetCurrentTennantId(),
       Extension = infoFile.Extension.Replace(".", "").ToLower(),
       UploadedBy = caseOfficer.Id,
       CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
       File = uniqueFilename,
       ContentType = fileAttachments.ContentType,
       isActive = true,
       isDeleted = false
    };
    if (PoiId != 0)  {
       attachments.PoiID= PoiId;
    }
    if (VesselId != 0) {
        attachments.VesselId = VesselId;                       
     }
     _context.Add(attachments);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

> There is some confusion above i am using to store something else the
> collection does not create this field it creates VesselsId with the
> extra s this is what is not being filled in.

```
 public int? VesselId { get; set; }
```

The collection creates this field

[image]

Comment: Can you share insertion code for `FileAttachments` to `Vessels ` ?

Comment: @MustafaArslan added upload code  shown above in edit 2  its a gereric upload method , their is a field called uploadarea I can use If I need to do some code that is different for vessels photos or else check that the VesselId is not 0

Comment: @rogue39nin Apparently the conditional code `attachments.VesselId = VesselId;` was not hit for your existing data, hence the `VesselId` of the inserted records in database is `null`.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev that is another field I am using to store it should be stored in [VesselsId] for the foreign key to work correctly if u look at the database screen shot. If u look at that line i have my if statment around its the field [VesselId] which is getting stored its the VesselsId pluarel that is causing the issue But when I check VesselsId is not in the FileAttachment Model is gererated by the icollection

Comment: What I'm saying is that if `VesselId == 0`, then according to your `if` statement `attachments.VesselId` won't be assigned and will have the default value `null`.

Comment: @IvanStoev again what I am saying is VesselsId and VesselId  are to differnt fields but I will try it in case

Comment: Got it - the extra `s` in name. It's because of the EF Core [FK name conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#fully-defined-relationships) and the fact that you use plural entity class names. If you use singular class names (as you should), you won't have such issues. Now you have to manually configure the relationships and [map the `VesselId` property as FK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key).

Comment: @IvanStoev I dont seem to be able to select with FileAttachments with the Has Many can you provide a code example I looked at the doc exmpale but in relation to my model aobve please

Comment: @IvanStoev when I attempt ur one i get the folllowing error The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FileAttachments_Vessels_VesselPhotosForeignKey". The conflict occurred in database "MISSystem", table "dbo.Vessels", column 'Id'.

Comment: @IvanStoev also the problem with that aprroach is what id I am not uploading a vessel  photo how do i get  and uploading something else would this not set it to that it cant be not null?

Comment: Because with your solution i get this SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FileAttachments_Vessels_VesselPhotosForeignKey". The conflict occurred in database "MISSystem", table "dbo.Vessels", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Thank u all got it working as it should do @IvanStoev if u place an answer I will mark thanks a million mate.

Answer (score 0):

Add relation to `FileAttachments` model like this

```
    public  class FileAttachments {
       ...
       [ForeignKey("Vessels")]
       public int? VesselId { get; set; }

       public Vessels Vessels { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi U have not said where to add that which table

Comment: But why not use ICollection is that a wrong aproach

Comment: If I do it ur approach I will always need a vessel sometimes it could be a poi that has a fileattachment and not a vessel could be attached multiple objects

Comment: This don't change your relationship model. This says `VesselId` is foreign key of `Vessels` to EntityFramework. It override default convention of EntityFramework. Default convention is foreign key for `Vessels` model is `VesselsId`.